# sencha app build production not working

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I created my app using the sencha create app command. It is working locally on my machine as well on our web server. I am trying to build the app for production but the following command is not working for me:

> sencha app build production

I'm not getting any error messages or output whatsoever. Nothing in the directory changes.

The following command:

> sencha build -p appname.jsb3 -v -d .

generates the jsb3 file. However, my index.html is never updated to load the new files. According to the information I have found online, my index.html should be updated to point to the new files.

I think I am missing something somewhere but I can't find any tutorials online that work for me. Can anyone point me in the right direction? My index.html is pasted below if that helps to determine what I'm doing wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html manifest="" lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>EGL Mobile</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        /**
         * Example of an initial loading indicator.
         * It is recommended to keep this as minimal as possible to provide instant feedback
         * while other resources are still being loaded for the first time
         */
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
        }

        #appLoadingIndicator {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-top: -10px;
            margin-left: -50px;
            width: 100px;
            height: 20px;
        }

        #appLoadingIndicator > * {
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            float: left;
            height: 20px;
            margin-left: 11px;
            width: 20px;
            -webkit-animation-name: appLoadingIndicator;
            -webkit-border-radius: 13px;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 0.8s;
            -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            -webkit-animation-direction: linear;
            opacity: 0.3
        }

        #appLoadingIndicator > :nth-child(1) {
            -webkit-animation-delay: 0.18s;
        }

        #appLoadingIndicator > :nth-child(2) {
            -webkit-animation-delay: 0.42s;
        }

        #appLoadingIndicator > :nth-child(3) {
            -webkit-animation-delay: 0.54s;
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes appLoadingIndicator{
            0% {
                opacity: 0.3
            }

            50% {
                opacity: 1;
                background-color:#1985D0
            }

            100% {
                opacity:0.3
            }
        }
    </style>
    <script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src="sdk/microloader/development.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="appLoadingIndicator">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you running the latest version of the SDK Tools? What version of Sencha Touch? What OS?

Comment: I am running the most current version of the SDK Tools as of about a month ago. I'm using a MAC.

Comment: The SDK Tools should not update the index.html. Instead, it should build your application into the `builds` folder depending on your build type (production in your case). Have you tried creating a fresh new build and trying to build that?

Comment: I generated a test app and executed the sencha app build production command on it and the build directory was populated with the production version of the app. This indicates that something is wrong in my app but I have no idea where to start looking. Would I be better off just creating a new app and adding the files from the old app to it?

Comment: Damn. That's what I would do. Also, you should use test/package instead of production, and production generates diffs and technically should only be used when you actually want to release for production.

Comment: Creating a new app and copying the old files to it solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

// first open cmd and run:

```
cd path/to/application
```

// then make sure index.html exists in you path/to/application:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <title>title</title>
 <!-- update this to your css file -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/app.css" type="text/css">
 <!-- you can get this file from sencha original files -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="sdk/sencha-touch-debug.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script> 
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

// make sure the file is loading your application and then run the command:

```
sencha create jsb -a index.html -p app.jsb3
```

// also execute the 2nd command. note the DOT at the end should be added to the command:

```
sencha build -p app.jsb3 -d .
```

// now our application is built:

Create new html file "built.html" and use the below code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/app.css" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sdk/sencha-touch.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="all-classes.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

// now open built.html